# How to checkpoint a RDD without saving all of its data?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am running a series of jobs and intermediate *rdd* is used in all jobs. So i have cached the intermediate *rdds* but after some iterations its slowing down. Then i used *rdd* check pointing after caching to break lineage which is not required. In spark UI i am able to confirm that check pointing is done correctly. But its also taking time because its writing each *rdd* to local system. What is the effective way to break unnecessary lineage without saving actual *rdd* data?

Answer (score 0):

The exact point of checkpointing is to save all data.This enables breaking lineage and "forgetting" about the past. Without saving the data breaking the lineage is simply not possible.

Comment: I want to cache the data first and then break lineage so that the data i am gonna play with in future is in RAM and at the same time the the history of the RDD is erased. And because data is in RAM, i don't want to store it in my local system.

Comment: For that you can directly use rddObject.cache()